A nice terminal inequality for martingales
Let $X_t$ be a continuous time martingale taking with $\sup_t \mathbb E[X_t^-] < \infty$, and $X_0 = 0$ almost surely. Assume further that $X_1$ admits a probability density function.
Is it true that there exists some $K > 0$ such that the function $H(t) := t \, \mathbb P[X_1 \geq t]$ is nonincreasing on $(K, \infty)$?
Remark: We can also consider a discrete time martingale, replacing $X_1$ with $X_\infty := \lim_{n \to \infty} X_n$, which is guaranteed to exist by the martingale convergence theorem. The same conclusion still holds I believe.

I hope I got the conditions down right this time - I really think there is something here! @user479223

Hm, I think so long as $X_1$ admits a pdf it should hold that enough spreading has occured for this to be true. I once again have forgotten to include this crucial condition. @FedorPetrov

… yeah… maybe on $(0, \infty)$ instead, I am not sure anymore. This is a subtle problem if there is anything here @FedorPetrov

@FedorPetrov I guess it is not true if you let the martingale accumulate say near to $-1$ and $1$.

as stated, it is natural to try large $\varepsilon$, so why do you denote it by $\varepsilon$?

@FedorPetrov I think it can hold for small $\epsilon$ too, but maybe i should use something more neutral like $K$.

If this were true, then it would imply that if $X$ is an arbitrary symmetric absolutely continuous $L^1$ random variable, then $t.P(X>t)$ is eventually non-increasing. This seems too good to be true.

@AnthonyQuas Ah… so any symmetric variable can be achieved as the terminal value of a martingale starting at $0$?

Just make it jump to the symmetric value at time 1.

Let $\rho$ satisfy $\rho=C\max(\cos x,0)e^{-x^2}$ where $C$ is chosen so that the integral is 1.
Then let $Z$ be a random variable with density $\rho$ and let $X_t$ be 0 for $t<1$ and $Z$ for $t\ge 1$. Then $H(t)$ is increasing on the intervals where $\rho$ is 0.

I'm not sure if you could get something better if you made the assumption that the sample paths were continuous. I suspect not, though.
